# Fetching all the users who are following certain person on twitter

Tags: python, twitter, social-networking, twython

I am new to the concept of python and Twython(the library using which we can retrieve the tweets from twitter).

Now I am retrieving tweets using

```
from twython import Twython
twitter=Twython()
user_timeline=twitter.getUserTimeline(screen_name="bjkbh")
```

I am getting the desired tweets but now i am want to know how many people are following a specific user.

In the tweets we can come to know the count of people following by

```
for tweets in user_timeline:

tweets['followers_count']
```

but how do I get the names of all the people following and the influence they exert?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's two different methods you can use for this; one that returns just follower IDs (`getFollowersIDs`), and one that returns the statuses/etc of a follower set (`getFollowersStatus`).

Some example code for one would be like the following:

```
from twython import Twython

twitter = Twython()
followers = twitter.getFollowersIDs(screen_name = "ryanmcgrath")

for follower_id in followers:
   print "User with ID %d is following ryanmcgrath" % follower_id
```

If you have IDs, you'd need to do further lookups yourself, so the latter method (`getFollowersStatus`) may be what you want. Keep in mind that Twython functions just mirror API key parameters from the official Twitter API docs, so the methods you can pass to an argument are the same as what you'll find on the docs.

Comment: Hi  sapan Thanks for the answr,but when i am doing as per your suggestion i got the following error
   .print "User with ID %d is following ryanmcgrath" % follower_id
   ....:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/vishal/<ipython-input-50-8141e3aa003d> in <module>()
      1 for follower_id in followers:
----> 2      print "User with ID %d is following ryanmcgrath" % follower_id
      3 

TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not unicode

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from twython import Twython

twitter = Twython()
followers = twitter.getFollowersIDs(screen_name = "ryanmcgrath")
followers = followers['ids']
print "The user rayanmcgrath has %s followers" % str(len(followers))
for follower_id in followers:
   print "User with ID %d is following ryanmcgrath" % follower_id
```

Comment: what if the account has more than 5000 users. this won't work!